# A special type of similarity that "inherits multiplication" over addition.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question, linear-transformations

Let us investigate a special type of similarity.

$$A = S(C^{-1}+D)S^{-1}$$

$$B = S(D^{-1}-C)S^{-1}$$

$$AB = S(C^{-1}D^{-1}+I - I - DC)S^{-1} \\= S((DC)^{-1}-DC)S^{-1}$$
$$BA = S(D^{-1}C^{-1}-I + I - CD)S^{-1} \\= S((CD)^{-1}-CD)S^{-1}$$

1. Multiplication does "transfer" to internals and result becomes a $B$-type matrix but with $D=C$, either equal to $CD$ or $DC$ in previous matrix.

Is that all there is to it or are there more things to discover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layer of $S^{-1}$ really amounts to the observation that similarity preserves addition and multiplication (and consequently, inverses).  That is, the map $X \mapsto SXS^{-1}$ is a [homomorphism of algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_homomorphism).  Since this map is invertible, it is also an *isomorphism*.

Stripping that away, you have observed that multiplying a "type-A" matrix with a "type-B" matrix produces another "type-B" matrix.  I'm not really sure what to make of that, honestly.  Maybe there's something to say in the case where $C,D$ belong to a class of matrices that is closed under multiplication.  For instance, where both $C,D$ are orthogonal/unitary.

Comment: Homomorphism is a very algebraic word, I am not sure I understand it so well yet.. Yes I am also not sure what to make of it. That is why I ask.